# Cube Default Measure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

If I execute the following `MDX` script

```
SELECT
FROM [CubeName]
```

It returns an answer giving the total of all the members in for the default measure.

Can I write an `MDX` statement that tells me what the default measure is or is it not possible to query meta-data with `MDX`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[DefaultMemberName] AS [Measures].DefaultMember.Member_Name
SELECT
    [Measures].[DefaultMemberName] ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: +1 thanks Alexander...I'd discovered that the following answers my question `SELECT [Measures] ON COLUMNS FROM [YourCube]` but your query is more explicit and I can see what is happening.